# How to cleanup azure databricks workspace

Tags: azure-databricks

I am migrating databricks workspace from one account to another account, in this process I need to refresh the databricks workspace with updated data (notebooks, users, groups, clusters, database and tables)
Do we have any process to cleanup the databricks workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Databricks workspace by using Microsoft given API.

To update the Azure Databricks workspace, you can use the below API which will update the specified workspace:

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/{workspaceName}?api-version=2018-04-01
```

[image]

To cleanup the resources, you can terminate the cluster. To do so, from the Azure Databricks workspace, from the left pane, select **Clusters**. For the cluster you want to terminate, move the cursor over the ellipsis under Actions column, and select the **Terminate** icon. This stops the cluster.

If you do not manually terminate the cluster it will automatically stop, provided you selected the **Terminate after __ minutes of inactivity** checkbox while creating the cluster. In such a case, the cluster automatically stops, if it has been inactive for the specified time.